# Java Generics : Type Inference Performance

Tags: java, performance

I was wondering what the performance penalty is for generic type inference in Java 7. Is the "generics method type inference" cost (i.e., [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/methods.html)) different from the "generics assignment type inference" cost (i.e., [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html))? I suppose the cost is negligible since type inference on generics is done in compile time?

Also, as far as "improved type inference" (i.e., [this](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/101)) in Java 8 (due to lambda's), does this also levy a performance hit? How is the performance cost for type inference in Java 8 different from that in Java 7?

I realize these are difficult (and possibly, ill informed) questions, and hence, welcome any input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is the "generics method type inference" cost (i.e., this) different from the "generics assignment type inference" cost (i.e., this)?

No.

> I suppose the cost is negligible since type inference on generics is done in compile time?

The cost is zero for that reason, unless you count compile time.

> Also, as far as "improved type inference" (i.e., this) in Java 8 (due to lambda's), does this also levy a performance hit?

This is zero as well. There is no 'also levy a performance hit' about it.

Answer (score 4):

As you supposed, generics are removed during compilation, and after that there are only pure (non-generic) classes.

The type inference in Java 7 is pretty simple to perform (of course still during compilation) so it won't impact on performance at all.

Answer (score 2):

Normal method type inference and constructor type inference (so called "diamond") are pretty much the same, the costs should be the same too.

Type inference is only done at compile time.

Java 7 inference rules are quite complicated, one can invent use cases that will cost compiler some time to figure out. However, most code in real world are not complicated, compiler usually can infer them very quickly.

Java 8 inference is much more complicated, and I would expect compiler to become noticeably slower. How much slower? - we'll have to wait and see.